# How to validate Check box if xpaths are same in case of selected and unselected

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

M unable to validate checkbox, if it's selected or not
because both the HTML are same

I tried isSelected(), but it's not working

Below is the HTML code for both selected and unselected

1) Selected

```html
<label class="c-account-access-panel__checkbox " for="23336" data-js-checkbox-label="">
<input id="23336" class="c-account-access-panel__checkbox-input" type="checkbox" 
data-label-for-value-missing="Please select at least one account from the options below" data-form-field-validation-on-grid="" 
required="" checked="" data-js-checkbox="" value="DE29973399" name="payer"/>
<div class="c-account-access-panel__checkbox-symbol"/>
```

2) Unselected

```html
<label class="c-account-access-panel__checkbox " for="23336" data-js-checkbox-label="">
<input id="23336" class="c-account-access-panel__checkbox-input" type="checkbox" 
data-label-for-value-missing="Please select at least one account from the options below" data-form-field-validation-on-grid="" 
required="" checked="" data-js-checkbox="" value="DE29973399" name="payer"/>
<div class="c-account-access-panel__checkbox-symbol"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you cross check once if both the HTMLs are same? They shouldn't be same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *Java Docs* [**`isSelected()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected--) method determines whether the element is selected or not. This operation only applies to `<input>` elements such as *checkboxes*, *options within a `<select>` tag and radio buttons*.

To validate if the desired checkbox is selected or not you can use the following code block:

```
boolean checkboxSelected = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='c-account-access-panel__checkbox-input' and @name='payer']")).isSelected();
```

Answer (score 0):

If *isSelected()* is not working for you. Then , you can use **JavascriptExecutor**  to do your task. Following **JS** statements shall let you know the state of target checkbox.

```
document.getElementById("23336").click();
document.getElementById("23336").checked;
```

The checked method returns true or false depending on the checkbox state.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate using `getAttribute`method.

First select the webElement using any of the unique locator,

```
 WebElement checkbox=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='checkbox']"));
```

If the checkbox is selected, then `checkbox.getAttribute("checked")`will give the result as `true` else, it will give the result as `null`. So, you can add the condition using `checkbox.getAttribute("checked")`

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath expression like: (//div [@id='23336')[1] or (//div [@id='23336')[2] to make them into unique element then do .isselected ()